# Can't access some member of JSON array Android

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I have `JSON array` like this

```
[
  {
    "ride_id": "48",
    "user_id": "22",
    "event_id": "42",
    "driver_id": "0",
    "pick_up_location": "11111"
  },
  {
    "ride_id": "48",
    "user_id": "21",
    "event_id": "42",
    "driver_id": "0",
    "pick_up_location": "11111"
  },
  {
    "name": "ofir rosner",
    "image": "",
    "address": "Yokne\\'am Illit, Israel"
  },
  {
    "name": "hhhh",
    "image": "profilePictureOfUserId22.JPG",
    "address": "ffffd"
  }
]
```

im using `OKhttp3` to retrieve my data like

```
 Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
     ...........
```

but the object of `JSONObeject` in place `i` only contains

```
{"ride_id":"50","user_id":"2","event_id":"44","driver_id":"0","pick_up_location":"11111"}
```

but I want to be able to do something like this `object.setString("name")`
or to get to the `object` in the place `i` for name, image and address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your all object don't have `name` key-value pair so you can use [`optString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.optString%28java.lang.String%29) ,  `It returns an empty string if there is no such key`

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = object.optString("name");

    // optionally use object.optString("name","No Name Found");
    // To display some default string as name 

    if(!name.isEmpty()){
        // we got the data , use it
        Log.i("name is ",name); // display data in logs
      }
}
```

or you can use [`has`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.has%28java.lang.String%29) which `Determine if the JSONObject contains a specific key.`

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String name;
    if(object.has("name")){
          name = object.optString("name"); // got the data , use it
      }
}
```

---

> ```
> {   // this object has no "name" key-value pair and so does some other object
>     "ride_id": "48",
>     "user_id": "22",
>     "event_id": "42",
>     "driver_id": "0",
>     "pick_up_location": "11111"
>   }
> ```

Comment: what do you mean by "Your all object don't have name key-value pair", but the array do have "name" in it and i want to access it

Comment: @styx check the example , your all object don't have `name` key value pair so you can use opt string which won't throw an exception in case the key is not there , instead give you empty string or you can confirm the presence of key using `has`

Comment: i know the object does not have "name" in it but i want to access the one who has

Comment: @styx i have added the code in my answer too , inside `if` use `String name` object which will show you data , if it is there

Comment: but the object does not have name in it so the `if` statement will return always false, also i checked the `JSONArray` length is 2 and not 4

Comment: @styx obviously , if there is no data then what exactly you want ?  or do you want some default dummy string as name-value if name key is not in the object ?